# Scope CSS to module only in Angular 5 to prevent bleeding into other parts of app

Tags: css, angular, angular2viewencapsulation

How do I scope CSS to only a module in Angular? When I load a module lazily, and have ViewEncapsulation.None in that module, the CSS bleeds into other parts of my app. Any idea how to prevent that, or keep that CSS only for that module in Angular 5?

Comment: *Not* use `ViewEncapsulation.None`?

Comment: I need to use ViewEncapsulation.None, as I want the style in the module, but didn't think it will affect other parts of the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such think as module CSS scope.

The default `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` does that per component. With `ViewEncapsulation.None` you disable that. There are no other ways provided by Angular.

You can add a CSS class or attribute to every component in a module and add that class or attribute to every selector in that module to limit the CSS to components of that module.

Comment: I was able to limit the scope by specifying a more specific CSS selector in the Component.  The result was the CSS is now only applied based on an element ID, that is only found in that one component.